# How to simulate desired number of birth-death trees?

Tags: r, simulation, phylogeny

I wonder How can I change below code so that desired number of trees is obtained. I know that one can run simulation for certain amount of time, but I need to simulate let's say 100 trees, all with 50 extant species. So if I try

```
Library(phytools)
Trees <- pbtree(b=1, d=0.3 , n=50, scale=NULL, nsim=100, type="continuous", extant.only=TRUE)
```

I get "tree returned  as NULL", so I want to keep  running until I have 100 trees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to simulate more trees and then keep the first 100 non-nulls

```
library(phytools)
allTrees <- pbtree(b=1, d=0.3 , n=50, scale=NULL, 
    nsim=200, type="continuous", extant.only=TRUE)
trees100 <- head(allTrees[!unlist(lapply(allTrees , is.null))], 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick glance, Trees is stored as a list of trees.

#### Get number of null trees

```
S<-0
index<-numeric()
for(i in 1:length(Trees)){if(is.null(Trees[[i]])){
   S<-S+1
   index<-c(index,i)}
 }
```

#### Generate trees and replace null with a non null tree

```
while(S>0){
tree<-pbtree(b=1, d=0.3 , n=50, scale=NULL, nsim=1, type="continuous", extant.only=TRUE)
if(!is.null(tree)){
    Trees[[index[1]]]<-tree
    S<-S-1
    index<-index[-1]
    }
}
```